# Play Framework auto-test does not work

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am trying to integrate a play application into Jenkins CI. I was looking for a way to automatically run all the tests.

Play [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/test#continuous) suggests that `play auto-test` runs all the tests automatically.

When I do `play auto-test` it does not seem to be running tests automatically as described in the documentation. It simply reads,

```
Go to http://localhost:9010/@tests to run the tests
```

and stays at that. I was curious if it was running the tests in the background and taking some time, so I checked the CPU usage which appeared to be near 100% all the time. I waited for about 25 minutes thinking it maybe running tests, but it still does not terminate and does not appear to be running tests. Running tests from browser using `play test` does not take more than couple of minutes.

I am running following environment

```
Play: 1.2.4
Java: Sun Java build 1.6.0_26-b03
OS: Ubuntu Linux 12.04
```

Has anyone else experienced similar issue?

Comment: Looking at the following links, I doubt if it even works! https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/956-differing-behaviour-for-auto-test-and-autotest https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Bb4AABp1vbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be with log4.properties file. Deleting this file gets `play auto-test` to work properly.

I created a property in the `application.conf` to use a separate log4j.properties file for the production environment.

```
%prod.application.log.path=log4j.prod.properties
```